# Squid-style external redirector for polipo doesn't work

Tags: python, http, proxy

I am trying to write a trivial squid-style redirector for polipo http proxy, as specified [in the documentation](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejch/software/polipo/manual/External-redirectors.html#External-redirectors).

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# based on
# http://gofedora.com/how-to-write-custom-redirector-rewritor-plugin-squid-python/

import sys

def modify_url(line):
    l = line.split(" ")
    old_url = l[0]
    new_url = "\n"
    if "experts-exchange" in old_url:
        new_url = "http://127.0.0.1/" + new_url
    return new_url
    
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    new_url = modify_url(line)
    sys.stdout.write(new_url)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

When running polipo with this redirector and trying to access [http://www.experts-exchange.com/](https://go.experts-exchange.com/), I get the following error:

```
500 Couldn't test for forbidden URL: Redirector error
```

Actually, I get the same error when trying to access any URL, which makes me think it's a problem with my redirector code.

The output in polipo's log doesn't provide more hints, all I see there is:

```
Redirector returned incomplete reply.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I have fixed modify_url() to return a value, because it did not. I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

That site (gofedora) mentions that you need to return either a blank line or the modified url in modify_url to make it work. Also you'll see the error if you run this manually. Your solution is to return new_url at the end of modify_url.

Please note that you also need to chmod +x to permit your proxy to run the script.

Comment: I missed the return value in modify_url() indeed. I've now fixed that (see the edited code above) but I still get the same error. The redirector is executable and readable (I run polipo as root for testing purposes but will change that later as soon as I make the redirector work), the filesystem doesn't have a noexec flag. I didn't understand your statement about manual run. The redirector is supposed to be called by polipo. And it's ok if python methods don't have explicit returns, they return None by default AFAIK.

Comment: @Daylight: I've installed polipo to my ubuntu 10.10 box via apt-get install polipo and copy-pasted your edited code above. I've chmodded the file, opened /etc/polipo/config and added line "redirector = /home/cem/redirect.py" (w/o quotes) and executed sudo service polipo restart . I've modified my firefox to use proxy (localhost:8123) and tried your url and another. It works as expected, so nothing wrong here, I think you're missing something. :)

Comment: @Daylight manual run means: Squid (or polipo) executes several instances (redirect_children X on squid) and passes a query with a pre defined format to them via stdin. So, as you already know, you just need to read from stdin and return via stdout. If you run your redirector manually, you need to provide an assumed input to your redirector and wait for a reasonable output. Assumed input is like http://experts-exchange.com 1.1.1.1/experts-exchange.com - GET - and you expect 127.0.0.1 for this. Btw, you're right about the return but sys.stdout.write(None) causes a TypeError ;)

Comment: I have just tried to reproduce my issue on Linux Mint 10 and I get exactly the same error.

Comment: @Daylight: I don't know about Mint but this works on my system. Just follow my comment on "Mar 25 15:38"